# using quantlib function in my c++ program

Tags: options, quantlib, programming

I want to include the QuantLib function for option greeks calculations in my own C++ code.
My question is: can I just include those functions? I don't want to use the rest of their stuff.

I obviously cannot just write:

```
QuantLib::europeanOption.delta()
```

I have included the header:

```
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>

using namespace QuantLib;
```

I wish they had some good documentation.

Comment: Since this is a programming-specific question, isn't this more appropriate for stack overflow?

Comment: ok, I'll ask there..

Comment: @sheegaon This question is about a specific quant library. The user is asking about how to include a single function. So if anyone knows which header that specific function is in, it would be an existing user of said library.

Comment: @chrisaycock there's no lack of questions about QuantLib on SO.  I'm just trying to direct the question to wherever it's most likely to get a good answer, particularly as the substance of the question has little to do with the functions in the library.

Comment: Maybe it's worth posting a Community Wiki post on how to actually use QuantLib in a new project? Can we do Wiki posts here on QF SE?

Comment: @Dmitri You can make a wiki simply by asking a question like, "How do I use QuantLib?" and then flagging it for community wiki. But then again, the true answer for a question like that is to refer the reader to the QL documentation.

Comment: @DmitriNesturuk I think the SE team is trying to cut down on uses of CW like that (see [The Future of Cummunity Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)).

Comment: I think this question is absolutely on topic here as it is. It is about a specific problem with a specific quant lib - so it fits in well in my opinion.

Comment: Shall we discuss this further [on meta](http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/q/170/1106)?

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as answer - thanks!

Comment: QuantLib now included as part of Ceemple, a rapid JIT based C++ technical coputing environment. Available (free) from http://www.ceemple.com.

Answer (score 17):

This is off-topic and maybe belongs to StackOverflow, but here goes.

**1. Compile QuantLib**

The best way is to open the *Visual Studio Command Prompt* using a shortcut under Programs→Microsoft Visual Studio→Visual Studio Tools. Now, you need to navigate to the `QuantLib` folder inside the folder where you have QuantLib (there are other folders such as `QuantLibXL` – that’s not the one you need.

Now, compile the whole of QuantLib by running the following command: `msbuild /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release QuantLib_vc10.sln`.

Inside this folder, if you look in the `lib` folder, you’ll get a lib file called `QuantLib-vc<VER>-mt.lib` and a corresponding file with a `-gd` suffix. You need these libs as well as the headers.

**2. Configure headers**

Right-click the project and choose Properties. Now, make sure you choose *All Configurations* in the configuration drop-down list box on the top-left of the window. 
First, navigate to ConfigurationProperties→C/C++→General. In the *Additional Include Directories*, add the path to QuantLib’s directory. If you add the `<QL Root>\QuantLib` directory, you will be able to reference QuantLib headers with statements such as `#include <ql/someheader.hpp>`. If you did it correctly and you’re using VS2010, IntelliSense will kick in *immediately*, meaning if you type `#include <ql/`, VS will show you a helper list with headers (which is useful).

**3. Configure library references**

Now, navigate down to Configuration Properties→Linker→General. In the *Additional Library Directories* add the path to the QuantLib’s `\lib` directory.

Now move down to the *Input* header under the *Linker* header. Edit the *Additional Dependencies* field, prepending it with the name of the QuantLib library file — you need to specify the filename (without the full path) of the `.lib` file you need to include. The `-mt.lib` file is used for the Release build, and the `-mt-gd.lib` for the Debug build. If you mess these up, you'll get errors.

**4. Run it**

By now, assuming you have the boost libraries in your VS `\include` folder, the following should compile and run without problem:

```
//first line is required in .NET
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace QuantLib;

void main()
{
  boost::shared_ptr<Money> m(new Money);
  cout << m->value() << endl;

  getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

How at ease are you with programming, dynamic linking, Makefiles and the rest?

In essence, there is no magic here. QL has a very liberal license, and you "merely" have to set up your project such that it finds

- the quantlib headers (and hence Boost headers) during compilation
- the quantlib library during linking

and both of those can be automated by calling `quantlib-config` with proper flags `--clags` and `--libs`, respectively.

This is *really* no different than linking to any other external library.

Comment: from my linux shell, `quantlib-config --libs` prints out `-L/usr/local/lib -lQuantLib` telling me to `g++ myQL.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lQuantLib -o my_executable`.  Docs for quantlib-config helper program: http://linux.die.net/man/1/quantlib-config